# Mac OS X NSPanel with NSTabView Keyboard Event: How do I use NSTabViewDelegate to display TabItem's View for keyboard navigation?

Tags: macos, nstabview

Mac OS X NSTabView: How Do I Display TabItem's View for keyboard navigation?

I have a  TabView that works just fine with the mouse. I want to make the NSTabView support keyboard navigation.

Using the Arrow Key moves through the various TabItems, but does not cause the TabItem view to 
appear. I need to click the tab in order to show the Tab's view.

When the Arrow Key is used, the NSTabViewDelegate method

```
tabView:shouldSelectTabViewItem:
```

is called and it returns YES. NO other NSTabViewDelegate method is called, hence its View is not displayed.

What is the best/recommended way to get the mouse click(show the View) action fired when
the TabItem is reached using the keyboard? Can this be fixed in Xcode
or do I have to involve subclassing and/or notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside MyAppController (mainWindow) the app originally used this code to put up editRecipeController's window, an NSPanel

// Original Code to launch the EditWindow as a sheet

```
    [NSApp beginSheet:[editController window] modalForWindow:[self window] modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:[editController window]];
    // sheet is up here...
    [NSApp endSheet: [editController window]];
    [[editController window] orderOut:nil];
    [[editController window] close];
```

Inside the Window, an NSPanel, there is an NSTabView.
The Panel is fully function using the mouse. It has a five Tab NSTabView. One Tab has an NSTextField, Three Tabs have an NSTextView. The fifth has an NSTableView.

The problem I had was as follows, when the user navigated from Tab to Tab using the ArrowKey,
The proper Tab was Highlighted, but did not become "selected", that is , its View was not
displayed. The only way to make the View appear was to click on the Tab with the mouse.

```
My goal is to have full keyboard support for the NSTabView
```

I was able to get the proper behavior for the NSTabView by following :
Hillegass' Book , Chapter 25, "Sheets.

```
    // MyAppController.m  - WindowController for mainWindow

    - (IBAction) editRecipeAction:(id)sender {
        // setup the edit sheet controller if one hasn't been setup already
        if (editRecipeController == nil){
            editRecipeController = [[EditRecipeController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"EditRecipe"];
            //[editRecipeController setMyAppController:self];
        }

        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:editRecipeController.window
                     modalForWindow:self.window
                      modalDelegate:editRecipeController
                     didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                         contextInfo:nil];
    }
```

//end MyAppController.m

// EditRecipeController.m

```
    - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
    {

        [NSApp endSheet:self.window returnCode:0 ] ;
        [self.window orderOut:self];
    }

- (void) sheetDidEnd:(NSWindow *) sheet returnCode:(int)returnCode contextInfo:(void *) contextInfo {

   DLog(@"sheet=%@",sheet);

}
```

If your goal is full keyboard support for such an NSTabView, I think you will need something
like the following use of an NSTabViewDelegate method:

```
    - (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)aTabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem{

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle ];
        NSNumber *tabNumber =
        [f numberFromString:tabViewItem.identifier];
        [f release];

        switch (tabNumber.integerValue) {
            case 1:
                editRecipeController.tabView.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.textViewIngredients;
                editRecipeController.textViewIngredients.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.cancelButton;
                editRecipeController.cancelButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.doneButton;
                editRecipeController.doneButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.tabView;
                break;
            case 2:
                editRecipeController.tabView.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.textViewDirections;
                editRecipeController.textViewDirections.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.cancelButton;
                editRecipeController.cancelButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.doneButton;
                editRecipeController.doneButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.tabView;
                break;
            case 3:
                editRecipeController.tabView.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.textViewDirections;
                editRecipeController.textViewDirections.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.cancelButton;
                editRecipeController.cancelButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.doneButton;
                editRecipeController.doneButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.tabView;
                break;
            case 4: // Comments
                editRecipeController.tabView.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.textViewComments;
                editRecipeController.textViewComments.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.cancelButton;
                editRecipeController.cancelButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.doneButton;
                editRecipeController.doneButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.tabView;
                break;
            case 5: //Categories - Table can not be edited 
                editRecipeController.tabView.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.cancelButton;
                editRecipeController.cancelButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.doneButton;
                editRecipeController.doneButton.nextKeyView = editRecipeController.tabView;
                break;
            default:
                DLog(@"switch value error");
                break;
        }// end switch

    }
```